# SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h File Not Found Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdwebimage

I Integrated SDWebImage in my project , its work like a charm in my mac system but while i am sending my project to other mac system its showing error like SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h File Not Found but the same project working in my system .some time i i am also getting the same error in my mac system after running the project continuously for 2 to 3 days

i tried all the ways like changing path to  project>target>Build Settings>'header search paths>$(SOURCE_ROOT)/SDWebImage

also tried $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR) -  In header search paths,

please give me the some suggestions to solve my problem

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

its only because the added SDWebimaege in your project its only reference so add folder of SDWebimages demo project in your project folder

and i am configure SDwebimage like this way:-

- you need to first right click on your project name:->add files to  yourProject-> selected SDWebImageproject and add them

NOTE:- please do not check copy option

- now click on project name in Your xcode going to build phases:->target dependencies:-> click on  + button and add SDWebimage ARC
- now select link binary with library click  + button add libSDWebimageARC.a and again  click  + and add imageIO.framework and also add libxml2.dylib thats it
- going to Build setting:->other link flag:-> add -ObjC
- and header search path add this three item

  1      /usr/include/libxml2

  2     "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include"

  3     "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include"

now build and run its working like smoothly cheers.... :)

Comment: @ganeshmanoj when you move Your project from one to another Mac you geetting refrerence so you must do again above step for particular mac in xcode i facing same prob and i fix like above :)

Comment: in another system also its worked fine but suddenly i got that problem

Answer (score 0):

just try heading this in your frameworks path as well:

$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks